# MSM live copy issue - child page property not inheriting from parent page properties

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr, aem-6

We have an application running smoothly in AEM 6.2 SP1. Currently we are trying to upgrade the AEM version to 6.4Sp2 with classic UI only. Our application is not touch UI compatible yet. After upgrading to AEM 6.4 everything works fine apart from MSM live copy inheritance.

We have a structure like 
content/xxx/us/parent_page --> content/xxx/ca/child page

Now this child page is a live copy of the parent page (there are no blueprints) and if we change some page properties from siteadmin in the parent page it should get reflected in the child page as well. This was working very well in AEM 6.2 but in 6.4 it is not working and even there are no notable error in error.log.

How to fix this.

Comment: Check if `on modify` rollout is configured on the parent page, if not try rolling out the page to the child page manually

Comment: Rollout config is standard rollout config.

Comment: check the OSGI configurations of "com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.actions.ContentUpdateActionFactory / CQ MSM Content Update Action". It has settings for excluding page properties "cq.wcm.msm.action.excludedprops", it could be misconfiguration of this property.